# Extract compilation time per compilation unit using SCons

Tags: c++, scons

I am using SCons to build my C++ application. I would like to extract the time it takes to build every compilation unit individually, such as:

```
a.cpp -> a.o - took 2.4 seconds
main.cpp -> main.o - took 5.1 seconds
```

I want to store these times in a database, per compilation unit.

The problem is that SCons comes built in with an Object/Program builder that builds the compilation units and I am not sure how to hook into those to add timing/database saving code. In a sense, I'm looking to wrap the already existing builder maybe.

What is a good way of achieving this?

Comment: To time something you can wrap it in a call to [time](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time)..

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know the time util, but did you actually read the question? How could I apply that to achieve what I described?

Comment: Would wrapping scons in a script work for you, then use scons --debug=time and parse the output.  If not you'll have to hack the actions for each compile and/or and a start and end action which would capture the time for each compile.

Comment: @bdbaddog ooh, that's a nice feature. That suffices for my needs, thank you

Comment: Added as answer so you can mark it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap scons in a script, then use `scons --debug=time` and parse the output.